# Read value of registry in c#

Tags: c#, registry

I have c# application which include code to retrieve registry values and check it's values.registry values stored in following manner:

MainKey:

```
Name:user123
Isregistered:no
```

however if Isregistered returns **"no"**,it will display appropriate message.

i am getting error like this

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

C# Code:

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\MainKey", true);
string currentKey;
currentKey = reg.GetValue("Isregistered", true).ToString();
if (currentKey == "yes")
{
  Console.WriteLine("availble");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Not availble");
}
```

i am getting error on 
**"currentKey = reg.GetValue("Isregistered", true).ToString();"**

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Not really related but you don't need the `@` escape character if you are escaping your backlash with the double backslash anyways

Comment: Either `reg` or the result of `reg.GetValue` is null. Which is it?

Comment: yes,it showing null values for **reg.GetValue**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

1)

```
// You're searching for HKEY_CURRENT_USER in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
// Use Registry.CurrentUser instead.
RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\MainKey", true);
string currentKey;
currentKey = reg.GetValue("Isregistered", true).ToString();
```

Find more about CurrentUser field [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.currentuser.aspx)

2)
 The other aspect is that either use @ or \\ not both in the registry path. i.e.

```
OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\MainKey", true);
```

or

```
OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\MainKey", true);
```

Find more about verbatim string literals [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You've used @ and escaped the backslash.
Also you'll want to ensue current key isn't null.

See the GetValue call here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open HKEY_CURRENT_USER using LocalMachine registry.
Use Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"MainKey", true) instead.